# Can I say "He's on a trip?"

Tags: sentence

Can I say He's on a trip?
Is it correct? 
if someone asks for my friend, and he is in China now. can I say He's on a trip?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between the words “journey”, “travel” and “trip”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168138/whats-the-difference-between-the-words-journey-travel-and-trip) and [What is the difference between trip and journey?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392697/what-is-the-difference-between-trip-and-journey) but both questions are closed :(

Comment: Is the person travelling coming back in a few days, weeks, or months? Is he on business, studying or on holiday? Your question needs context. The sentence as it stands is grammatical, beyond that nothing more can be added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say that in an informal context.

Comment: how about a formal situation? what's the suitable one for that?

Comment: That depends on how formal the situation is and its context.

Comment: Name one formal situation in which you *couldn't* say that—and indicate what you *would* say instead. (I find this claim to be strange.)

Comment: You *can* say it in formal situations, but depending on the situation, it can be less suitable. "He's on a trip." is already less formal than "He is on a trip.", because of the abbreviated "is". So, in a formal situation (e.g. when talking to customers), I would rather not use the abbreviation of "is".   But maybe I am too picky about it.

Comment: I am still waiting for the substitutions of it for formal situations.